# pkcs11interop generate key pair(EC or ECDSA), get error

Tags: c#, bouncycastle, elliptic-curve, ecdsa, pkcs11interop

This is my code :

```
X9ECParameters x9Ec = NistNamedCurves.GetByName("P-256");
X962Parameters x962 = new X962Parameters(x9Ec);
byte[] paramsBytes = x962.Parameters.GetDerEncoded();

List<IObjectAttribute> publicKeyAttributes = new List<IObjectAttribute>
                        {
                            session.Factories.ObjectAttributeFactory.Create(CKA.CKA_KEY_TYPE, CKK.CKK_EC),
                            session.Factories.ObjectAttributeFactory.Create(CKA.CKA_TOKEN, true),
                            session.Factories.ObjectAttributeFactory.Create(CKA.CKA_PRIVATE, false),
                            session.Factories.ObjectAttributeFactory.Create(CKA.CKA_LABEL, userParams.KeyLabel),
                            session.Factories.ObjectAttributeFactory.Create(CKA.CKA_ID, ckaId),
                            session.Factories.ObjectAttributeFactory.Create(CKA.CKA_ENCRYPT, true),
                            session.Factories.ObjectAttributeFactory.Create(CKA.CKA_VERIFY, true),
                            session.Factories.ObjectAttributeFactory.Create(CKA.CKA_VERIFY_RECOVER, true),
                            session.Factories.ObjectAttributeFactory.Create(CKA.CKA_WRAP, true),
                            session.Factories.ObjectAttributeFactory.Create(CKA.CKA_EC_PARAMS, paramsBytes)
                        };

List<IObjectAttribute> privateKeyAttributes = new List<IObjectAttribute>
                        {
                            session.Factories.ObjectAttributeFactory.Create(CKA.CKA_KEY_TYPE, CKK.CKK_EC),
                            session.Factories.ObjectAttributeFactory.Create(CKA.CKA_TOKEN, true),
                            session.Factories.ObjectAttributeFactory.Create(CKA.CKA_PRIVATE, true),
                            session.Factories.ObjectAttributeFactory.Create(CKA.CKA_LABEL, userParams.KeyLabel),
                            session.Factories.ObjectAttributeFactory.Create(CKA.CKA_ID, ckaId),
                            session.Factories.ObjectAttributeFactory.Create(CKA.CKA_DECRYPT, true),
                            session.Factories.ObjectAttributeFactory.Create(CKA.CKA_SIGN, true),
                            session.Factories.ObjectAttributeFactory.Create(CKA.CKA_SIGN_RECOVER, true),
                            session.Factories.ObjectAttributeFactory.Create(CKA.CKA_UNWRAP, true),
                            session.Factories.ObjectAttributeFactory.Create(CKA.CKA_SENSITIVE, true)
                        };
```

and I got the error message:

> "Method C_GenerateKeyPair returned CKR_ATTRIBUTE_VALUE_INVALID"

Am I miss any attributes or this template something wrong?
please help if anyone knows, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove encrypt/decrypt, wrap/unwrap.
It is not like RSA, you can't do this